# Getting CNContactStore Null on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on getting contact list from the device and I am using CNContactStore , It is working fine on the iPhone but getting error on the iPad,

```
 CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
```

on iPad getting store object as a null . So is CNContactStore supported on iPad or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CNContactStore is supported on iPad:

> This framework is available on all Apple platforms...

(From [Contacts API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts))

However it is only supported by iOS 9 onwards.

Comment: But my iPad has iOS 9 installed

Comment: @V-Xtreme Then something else is wrong. CNContactStore is supported on iPad and is supported on iOS9. I just ran it on my iOS 9 iPad and it works fine.